# Invoking a toString method from another class

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, tostring

Below is my `toString()` method in which I am trying to invoke another `toString()` from a different class called `Tree`. I am trying to return each part of an `ArrayList` and format it into my `toString()` from my `Tree` class, then put it all into the "result" `String`.

So far, all my method does is go through the list and return nothing. How do I make it so it essentially puts the entire list into the result string, under the format of my `toString()` from my `Tree` class?

```
   public String toString(){
        String result;
        int i = 0;
        while(i < listOfTrees.size()){
            listOfTrees.get(i);
            i++;
    }
```

Comment: a) your code, as posted, will not compile; b) you never return a `String` (which you declare in your method signature) and c) you never append the values of your `Tree` into a `String` for returning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `StringBuilder`. Get each `String` append it to the builder and then return the final `String` produced by it

```
   public String toString(){
        StringBuilder str= new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0; i < listOfTrees.size(); i++){
            str.append(listOfTrees.get(i));
        }
        return str.toString();
    }
```

The other way to do it is to initialize `result` with an empty `String` literal to start with and then use the `+` operator to add other `String`s to it, but this is awfully inefficient as `String`s are immutable and each time you add a `String` that way, you create a whole new object.

Comment: Unfortunately in my class I haven't yet learned about the StringBuilder, so I believe I will have to do it as you said and create a second String and keep adding it to my result String

Comment: @CodyTimmer you could use +=

Comment: Yeah, you don't  need two variables to do this, just use `result+= listOfTrees.get (i);` inside the loop.

Comment: Yup thats what I'm doing, to format each one with my other tostring method would result += listOfTrees.get(i).toString work?

Comment: Yeah, but even if you don't  call the `toString()` method, it will implicitly called for you when you use the `+=` operator.

Answer (score 1):

Use a StringBuilder :

```
   public String toString(){
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        int i = 0;
        while(i < listOfTrees.size()){
            result.append(listOfTrees.get(i) + " "); // this would use the toString
                                                     // method of the type contained
                                                     // in this List
            i++;
        }
        return result.toString();
   }
```

Comment: Thanks I think this will work, do you know if there is a way to do this without the StringBuilder? Because I haven't yet learned about those

Comment: @CodyTimmer You can do it with a String. If result is a String. You can change the loop to `result += listOfTrees.get(i) + " "`. This will return a new String that contains the original String in addition to the added String.

Comment: Yup thats what I'm doing, to format each one with my other tostring method would result += listOfTrees.get(i).toString    work?

Comment: @CodyTimmer Yes, if you don't forget the `()` in the method call, but it would append all the elements with no separators, which won't be very readable.

Comment: in my tostring method i have a \t at the end to space them each out with a tab